# Warning related to IUpdater?

Tags: .net, revit-api

I'm receiving this warning in Revit on a few machines related to ONE project...

"you are trying to synchronize was modified by the third-party updater Unknown : Element Updater which is not currently installed."

Background...
I have been working on a plug in that uses the IUpdater Interface, and am afraid I may be the cause of this issue.  From what I understand, this interface needs to be Registered, and then Unregistered.  So in the OnStartup sequence of the App, a say this (I'm omitting the registration of triggers etc...)...

```
     public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication a)
        {
            UpdaterFloorsROofsWalls elementUpdater = new UpdaterFloorsROofsWalls(a.ActiveAddInId);
            UpdaterRegistry.RegisterUpdater(elementUpdater);

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
```

and on Shut down, I am attempting to unregister the IUpdater...

```
     public Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication a)
        {
            // IUpdater is required to be Unregistered on shut down
            UpdaterFloorsROofsWalls elementUpdater = new UpdaterFloorsROofsWalls(a.ActiveAddInId);
            UpdaterRegistry.UnregisterUpdater(elementUpdater.GetUpdaterId());

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
```

As additional information, this is the IUpdater Class...

```
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WarningViewer
{
    internal class UpdaterFloorsROofsWalls : IUpdater
    {
        static AddInId m_appId;
        static UpdaterId m_updaterId;

        public UpdaterFloorsROofsWalls (AddInId id){
            m_appId = id;
            m_updaterId = new UpdaterId(m_appId, new Guid("FBFBF6B2-4C06-42d4-97C1-D1B4EB593EFF"));
        }

        public void Execute(UpdaterData data)
        {
            try
            {
                Document doc = data.GetDocument();
                if (doc.ActiveView.Name == _Utilities.viewName)
                {
                    List<ElementId> failingElements = _Utilities.GetElementIdsOfFailingElements(doc);
                    _Utilities.ShowAllWarningsIn3dSub(failingElements, doc, doc.ActiveView);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) 
            
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            
        }

        public string GetAdditionalInformation()
        {
            return "Updater for Floors Roofs and Walls";
        }

        public ChangePriority GetChangePriority()
        {
            return ChangePriority.FloorsRoofsStructuralWalls;
        }

        public UpdaterId GetUpdaterId()
        {
            return m_updaterId;
        }

        public string GetUpdaterName()
        {
            return "Element Updater";
        }
    }
}
```

And attached is the warning other machines are dealing with...
[image]

Question... Am i causing this warning even though my plug in not installed on those machines (I'm pretty sure I am)?  I can see how this would be the case if i were not unregistering this correctly.  I thought i was unregistering this correctly, but perhaps I am not. I'm not quite sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Afaict from your description, you have installed the updater on a local system, so it will be triggered by modifications of the local copy of the model. Then, you are trying to synchronise your local copy with the central model, where no updater is installed, and therefore the corresponding update cannot be executed. This all sounds a bit tricky and risky to me.

That aside, here are some notes on dynamic updaters and how they can be removed if needed:

- The Building Coder topic group 5.31. Dynamic Model Updater Framework DMU
- VSTA to Stay and Updater to Go
- DevDay@au Chronicle Estorage View Depth Sound of Noise
- Dynamic Model Updater Tutorial and Wizard Update
- Get Project Parameter Id and Prevent Updater Loop
- Simple IUpdater and other TBC Updates
- Naughty Updaters, DIY Add-In Manifest, GD, AI, etc.

Comment: Lots of reading to do tonight.... thanks Jeremy!

Comment: So based on this, is a less risky approach to create the IUpdater upon "Document Opened" and then unregister it on a "Synchronizing" event and then re-register it on a "Synchronized event"?  If this is a "Risky" approach, im curious where I missed this warning in the documentation. Most examples illustrate it's creation during "onstartup" and its destruction "onshutdown".

Comment: Hard for me to comment on, no personal experience on that. Sounds sensible, though. I would recommend trying it out and testing thoroughly. If you run into any difficulty, I would raise that in a succinct, precise and above all interesting problem description in the Revit API discussion forum, where more of your experienced peers might notice and be willing to contribute their thoughts and own observations.